# Arrays in function parameters?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to do the following (or an equivalent):

```
function a(foo, bar[x]){
    //do stuff here
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not valid syntax. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Javascript is not a static language, so just `bar` fits. You can't expect an array, but you can validate the argument at the top of the body.

Comment: No, that make no sense :) what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: What you should be doing is to resolve the bar[x] first and pass THAT into the function.

Answer (score 4):

Since JavaScript is not statically typed, you cant insist on an array.  You can do something like this: (far from perfect but usually does the job)

```
function a(foo, bars) {
  if (!Array.isArray(bars))
    bars = [bars];

  // now you are sure bars is an array, use it
}
```

I find that naming arrays in the plural, e.g. "bars" instead of "bar", helps, YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

yes, it is possible, as you have noticed you never especify de type of your variables, you only do `var a = 1` so here is the same case, you dont have to tell javascript it is an array, just pass it, it will work

```
function myFunction(foo, array){

}
```

and the call

```
var myFoo = { name: 'Hello' };
var myArray = [ 1, 2 ]
myFunction(myFoo, myArray);
```

hope it helps

Comment: That's answered my question! Thank you!